# visual studio lldb.exe liblldb.dll not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm, lldb

I installed clang tools in Visual Studio.

Clang works fine.

But when running lldb.exe, it says liblldb.dll not found

[image]

Comment: Your first step is to locate `liblldb.dll` and then make sure the folder containing is one of the folders listed in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the same report on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lldb-fails-to-start-because-liblldbdll/10392293?q=lldb).
And I did not find liblldb in Visual Studio.

1. So you need to download LLVM from [GitHub  website](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-16.0.0). E.g. install LLVM-16.0.0-win64.exe.Check **adding LLVM to system path**.
2. In addition, to launch lldb.exe, python310 is required. You can to search python310 using browser and install it from the official website resource.  Check **Adding python to the system path** in the python installer.

Then restart Visual Studio x64 command prompt to use lldb.exe.

Answer (score 0):

It causes the lack of dll or its path. You can place the DLL in the same path as the executable of lldb.exe, or you need to insert your DLL directory of ClangTools in the %PATH% variable, and Windows will then find the DLL there.

```
set PATH=C:\path_to_dll;%PATH%
```